# Grub 2 config menu : how to replace enter key with tab

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, keyboard, bootloader

My keyboard `enter` key is not working . Unfortunately Amazon us does not carry my keyboard as of now in stock. In the meantime I have a 4 boot option menu in my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` last of which is `windows` ( all others are variations of `Linux` ) . I want to find an interim solution e.g. *replace enter key with tab*. My external USB keyboard does NOT work in the `Grub menu`. It works in `BIOS` ( yeah ) and then within the `O.S` but `GRUB` does not seems to like it. Another solution would be to auto cycle through various choices followed by Y / N to choose.  Is any of this stuff possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>→</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This works out of the box, nothing to configure to do so.